# Rails load order changes class definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very strange bug that I've never come across and cannot find an answer to anywhere. I have a class definitions that looks like this:

```rb
# app/models/base/cache_key.rb
class Base
  class CacheKey
    class_attribute :cache_key_template, :instance_writer => false
    self.cache_key_template = "base:tracker-%s-%s"
  end
end

# app/models/other/cache_key.rb
class Other
  class CacheKey < ::Base::CacheKey
    self.cache_key_template = "other:tracker-%s-%s"
  end
end
```

However, when I jump into a console session, it does some funky-ness

```rb
$ rails console
> Base::CacheKey.cache_key_template
=> "base:tracker-%s-%s"
> Other::CacheKey.cache_key_template
=> "base:tracker-%s-%s"
> Other::CacheKey
=> Base::CacheKey
```

Hmm, weird. How about the other way around?

```rb
$ rails console
> Other::CacheKey.cache_key_template
=> "other:tracker-%s-%s"
> Base::CacheKey.cache_key_template
=> "base:tracker-%s-%s"
> Other::CacheKey
=> Other::CacheKey
```

I'm really stumped on this one.

Comment: What are the paths where these classes are defined? That might have an impact on the Rails autoload behavior. E.g. are they in `app/models/base/cache_key.rb` and `app/models/other/cache_key.rb` or something else? Also what version of Rails?

Comment: For the auto-loader to properly handle these each should be defined in its own file. Having `Other` defined in some other file cause confusion, it should be in `other.rb`.

Comment: The Rails version is 4.0.5 and they are specified in the equivalent `app/models/base/cache_key.rb` and `app/models/other/cache_key.rb`

Comment: You are definitely missing something critical here - rails 4.0.5 defines a module constant on first call to `Base::CacheKey` blocking further class declaration with this name. While requiring manually gives [very predictable results](http://pastebin.com/4skRrMAN). Thus either try to isolate the issue in new rails application, or `rgrep 'Other\|Base'` in your 'Rails.root'... not sure what to suspect, but somehow your app doesn't define `module Base` when you call for `Base::CacheKey`.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your file structure and got different results, which is funny.

```
pry(main)> Other::CacheKey.cache_key_template
TypeError: Other is not a class

pry(main)> Other::CacheKey
TypeError: Other is not a class
pry(main)> Other.class
=> Module
pry(main)> Base
=> Base
pry(main)> Base.class
=> Module
```

Looks like Rails initializes namespaces as modules. Do you have `Base` and `Other` defined elsewhere as classes?

Edit: 
I defined `base.rb` and `other.rb` in `/models` with their respective empty classes. Calling `cache_key_template` on both classes in either sequence works as expected now.

What's your implementation of `base.rb` and `other.rb` like?